# How to render incrementally images taken from the database

Tags: angular8

In a project which I am doing there is a part which involves rendering images taken from the database. One image is rendered without a problem, but when I try to incrementally render all the rows from the database, there starts to be a problem:

main.component.ts

```
homeDetails() {

this.info.getHomeDetails().subscribe(

     gethomedetails =>  {

                    this.id = gethomedetails[0].id;
                    this.picByte = gethomedetails[0].picByte;

                 // for ( let i=0; i<=gethomedetails.length; i++) {
                  // this.id = homedetails[0].id;
                   this.picByte = gethomedetails[i].picByte;
                  this.id = gethomedetails[i].id;
                  console.log("id" + this.id);
                 // this.picByte = homedetails[i].picByte;
                 // }
                  this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.picByte;
                 // }
                  console.log("retrievedimage" + this.retrievedImage);

                  // for (let i=0; i<=this.id; i++) {

                  //   console.log("id" + i);
                  // }

                  // for (let i=0; i<=this.id; i++) {

                  //   this.picByte = homedetails[i].picByte;

                  // this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.picByte;
                  // console.log("retrievedimage" + this.retrievedImage);
                  // }

                  // this.images = homedetails
      }
)

   // return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.retrievedImage);
  }
```

main.component.html

```
 <img [src]="retrievedImage">    works just for one file
```

Could you please point me out how I should do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a simple manner:

```
homeDetails() {
  this.info
    .getHomeDetails()
    .subscribe(data =>
        this.images = data.map(data => (
          {
            id: data.id,
            src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.picByte
          }
        )
    )
}
```

And then in the HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img [src]="image.src">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it did help :)